# How do I package a object module replacement for distribution via smpe

Tags: zos

How do I create an SMP/E jobstream to install an object module replacement as a PTF?

I have read the IBM manuals on SMP/E and have yet to find any viable examples to do create such a jobstream.

If anyone can offer any advice or assistance I sure would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking about creating the PTF, creating a job to install it, or both?

For creating the PTF, the doc for the ++MOD MCS has complete examples.  If the module already exists and was initially installed by SMP/E, and you're not changing anything about how it's installed, then you don't need any keywords on the ++MOD statement.  The examples are more complicated than you need in that case, because they show how to make changes, but the second one is a module replacement, and you can omit the DISTLIB and LEPARM keywords from it: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/3.1.0?topic=examples-example-2-specifying-link-edit-utility-attributes-leparm

Two concerns stand out as not covered by the example because they go beyond illustrating details of the ++MOD MCS itself:

1. Which format is your module in?  If it's TXT, you can just include it in the PTF as-is, since that's fixed-byte 80-character records that will never start with "++".  If it's GOFF, you'll have to transform it with GIMDTS:  https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/3.1.0?topic=routines-gimdts-data-transformation-service-routine
2. If the module was added or previously replaced by another PTF, you'll need to add a PRE or SUP for that PTF to the VER statement, so SMP/E knows what order to apply them in:

   `++VER(Z038) FMID(yourfmid) PRE(lastptf).`

For jobs to install the PTF, see the RECEIVE, APPLY, and ACCEPT processes under Installing corrective service: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/3.1.0?topic=guide-installing-corrective-service

You might have to supply additional parameters on the JOB statement as appropriate on your system.

Comment: Actually, its both, the module in question is sitting in an object lib recfm FB(80) but its a C module.

Comment: Glenn, I realize this is a lot to ask but is there anyway you could provide me an example of what the job stream would look like to receive a ptf that consisted of a object module ?

Comment: In the RECEIVE example, the comments show where you would include the PTF in the job using "DD *".  After "//SMPPTFIN DD *", put in the actual contents of the PTF: "++PTF(xxxxxxx)." then "++VER(Z038) FMID(yourfmid)." then "++MOD(modname)." then the contents of the module, and then continue with //SMPCNTL.